# jQuery: appending data to an ordered list

Tags: jquery

I have a list with each item having a numbered class. I want to append data after a specific class, but the problem is the item number may not exist. Is there a simple solution to this?

```
data = '<li class="3"></li>';
num = 2;

$('ul .'+num).append(data);

<ul>
    <li class="1"></li>
    // data should be appened here
    <li class="5"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: class names should begin with numbers

Comment: Yes there is a solution but the question is unclear. 
If the item number does not exist then do what - find where to put the data by making what decisions? What happens if it does exist?

Comment: checkout http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PTKTN/2/

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to do the following:

- Check if the element with that class exists. If not, go iterate until you can find the next largest element and prepend the element to it.

If you really wanted performance, you could do **binary search** so that you don't query the DOM as much.

```
var data = '<li class="3"></li>';
var $ul = $('ul');
var num = 2;

var $li;
var $currentLi = $ul.find('li.' + num);
// Go through the iterative search if the li wasn't found.
if ($currentLi.length === 0) {
    // Iterate and find the right spot
    var $lis = $ul.find('li');

    var elIndex = 0;
    var currentNumber = $lis.first();
    // Iterate until we found the sweet spot or we're at the end of the lis
    while (currentNumber < num && elIndex < $lis.length) {
        ++elIndex;
        $currentLi = $lis.eq(elIndex);
        currentNumber = parseInt($currentLi.attr('class'));
    }
    // By here you will have the $currentLi found.
}
$currentLi.append(data);
```

The solution might be simpler if you save the list order in an array in javascript or if you know more information about the list.

Hope that helps though.